# What's the rate limit on the square connect api?

Tags: square-connect

Currently the documentation just says:

> If Connect API endpoints receive too many requests associated with the same application or access token in a short time window, they might respond with a 429 Too Many Requests error. If this occurs, try your request again at a later time.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for them?

Comment: The Square engineering team checks on questions tagged square-connect and answers, so it is for them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, Connect API rate limits are on the order of 10 QPS. This limit might change in the future and should not be relied on.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to have a general idea. Much appreciated!

Comment: Is this api limit per app id or per oauth token? Much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above, is this per merchant or per app? Or per something else?

Comment: This API limit is per OAuth Client ID + Bearer Token