# Downloading (and storing) all of a merchants payments

Tags: square-connect

I'm writing an application that integrates with square and requires that I download and store the entire history of a merchant's payments at sign-up. What is the best way to download the entire history of payments?

In [this PHP example](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v1/php/payments-report.php), the author repeatedly requests the `v1/<location>/payments` endpoint until all payments have been pulled. Is repeatedly hitting that endpoint the best/only way to download all payments? If so, considering the [rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033966/whats-the-rate-limit-on-the-square-connect-api) for the connect API and the potential for many users to be signing up and triggering full history downloads at the same time, how can I prevent my requests from getting blocked?

The above issue is mainly about a one-time sync of payments from square to my application. Is there a preferred way to keep my application's set of payments for a merchant in sync with square's set of payments for a merchant into the future? i.e. a way to 1) download all payments on sign-up and 2) download any future payments as they become available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the v2/transactions endpoints, as they are more performant. You are correct in your approach, I would be sure to implement a robust back off strategy if you do end up hitting the rate limit. Depending on the merchant size, downloading the full transaction history likely won't take more than a minute or so.

To keep the transactions up to date, you can regularly pull new transactions and do diffs, or utilize [webhooks](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#webhooks-overview)